# How do I properly deal with null values and 'where' using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

So I'm in a sticky situation where I have a collection of items of a certain model. For simplicity sake I've made a small model named `CarModel`. In the collection it will have x amount of `CarModel` where some of the objects have properties where the value is null.

As for right now, it will run the `where` LINQ statement just fine on the first 3 items because they are null because it can check whether `null == null`.. However, it **can't** check whether `"Test" == null`, hence why I'm currently getting the exception

> System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
> value'

on this line `cars.Where(x => x.Name?.ToLower().Contains(car.Name?.ToLower()) == true).ToList();`

I was thinking about making the `Name` property nullable to test if that would work but I'm tied to `.NET Framework 4.0` and I'm not allowed to change it so I can't use nullable properties because that required C# 8.0 and the language version is tied to the framework so I'm on C# 7.3

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var car = new CarModel();
        car.Name = null;
        
        var cars = new List<CarModel>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            cars.Add(new CarModel { Name = null });
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            cars.Add(new CarModel { Name = "Test" });
        }

        var t = cars.Where(x => x.Name?.ToLower().Contains(car.Name?.ToLower()) == true).ToList();
    }
}

internal class CarModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Year { get; set; }
}
```

How do I properly filter if some properties might be null at times. The goal right there is to return a collection of 3 items that it found because it matches the conditions in the WHERE statement.

Answer (score 1):

In the provided example `car.Name` is always `null`, but I assume that you've got an actual use case where that's not always true.

The exception you're getting is from the `Contains` method, which can't handle a `null` parameter. You'll need to add a check for that, either skipping the entire section (not shown) that deals with the matching list or initialize an empty list when `car.Name` is null. Something like:

```
var t = car.Name is null ? new List<CarModel>() : 
    cars.Where
    (
        x => x.Name?.Contains(car.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == true
    ).ToList();
```

That's assuming that you don't want to match `null` with `null` (as Yong Shun's answer does).

To be honest though, it might make more sense to ensure that your `CarModel` object doesn't accept `null` name values. Required a name in the constructor, use a property setter that throws on `null` and so on. Depending on use case, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Just filter out the nulls before using the contains, you can't do a contains on a null value.

```
var t = cars.Where(x => x.Name != null && x.Name.ToLower().Contains(car.Name)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can write the query with dealing with 2 conditions:

1. When the input value is `null`, query `Name` with `null`.
2. When the input value is not `null`, query `Name` with not `null` and perform a case-insensitive search.
3. Conditions 1 & 2 with `or` (fulfill either one).

```cs
var t = cars.Where(x => (car.Name == null && x.Name == null)
    || (car.Name != null && x.Name != null && x.Name.ToLower().Contains(car.Name.ToLower()) == true))
    .ToList();
```

[Sample program](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oZW6E5)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get the exception error is because Contains method requires non-null argument.

so you should revise your code like below,

```
var t = cars.Where(x => x.Name?.ToLower().Contains(car.Name?.ToLower() ?? string.Empty) == true).ToList();
```